# What does dash "-" mean in svg's d attribute?

Tags: svg

I found some compressed svg like this:

`<path fill="#FFFCFB" d="M166.16 111.16c-.46.57-.97.9-1.52 1a20.68 ....`

What does `-` mean in this case?

I read the document about svg's d attribute but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` is the minus sign, for a negative coordinate value.